# How to Deploy Lambda functions through Serverless framework with existing s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on a project where I need to upload JS scripts using AWS Lambda serverless.

I provided the following functions in the Yaml file:

```yaml
 index:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: s3-bucket-name
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: auction/
          existing: true
```

I can activate an S3 bucket in a Lambda function using the code above, however another S3 bucket is automatically created as well.

Can any one help on this?

Comment: What is the name of your another s3 bucket . f this bucket `s3-bucket-name` is already present  in AWS s3 it can't create with the same name as bucket name are unique in Aws S3.  Can you share some examples of what another bucket this serverless.yml creating for you?